# Dynamic content of resize image in sharp aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, image-resizing, sharp

I am using `sharp` to resize images on `AWS Lambda`.
It works fine for testing but the issue is that how to give dynamic content type according to the content type of image.

My code is

```
then(buffer => S3.putObject({
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: dstBucket,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    Key: dstKey,
  }).promise()
)
```

I want this contentType is according to buffer content Type.